# How to add filter based on the maximum of group field value in pymongo aggregations

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, elasticsearch-aggregation

In my MongoDB collection, each documents has a field `score` and a filed `query`, so I am trying to group documents by `query`, i.e., get groups of documents with the same `query` filed, and meanwhile, I only want those groups containing files with `score` = 3 (range of `score` is 0,1,2,3). Here is my first aggregation clause:

```
agg = [{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$query",
        "src_ids": {"$push": "$src_id"},
        "sources": {"$push": "$source"},
        "scores": {"$push": "$score"}
    }
}]
```

So I guess, I have to add a `$match` regarding the maximum in `scores` in `agg`, but how should I do that?

===========================

**Edit**

if we have 6 files:

`{"query": "bread", "score": 2, ...}`

`{"query": "bread", "score": 1, ...}`

`{"query": "meat", "score": 2, ...}`

`{"query": "meat", "score": 3, ...}`

`{"query": "fruit", "score": 0, ...}`

`{"query": "fruit", "score": 3, ...}`

So here by the using the above aggregation clause: `db.collection.aggregate(agg)`, we have 3 groups of: `bread`, `meat`, `fruit`. However, if we consider the score issue, bread should not be returned.

Comment: Can you give some example like, what is your expectation and what is the current result?

Comment: @Mani See edits, thanks.

Comment: Hope can be explained why duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @Mani, in fact it's pretty simple but I am very new to Mongodb.

```
agg = [{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$query",
        "src_ids": {"$push": "$src_id"},
        "sources": {"$push": "$source"},
        "scores": {"$push": "$score"},
        "max_score": {"$max": "$score"}
    }},
    {
    "$match": {
        "max_score": {"$eq": 3}
    }}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the added match condition will look in the scores array for 3.

```
agg = [
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$query",
        "src_ids": {"$push": "$src_id"},
        "sources": {"$push": "$source"},
        "scores": {"$push": "$score"}
    }
},
{
    "$match": {
        "scores": 3
    }
}
]
```

Comment: thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: I hope this answered your question.